# Prometheus use case for high scale clickstream data

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus

We are getting website clickstream data ( at scale of 100 million events per minute)

Now our current pipeline takes all theses events on Kafka and form there spark for aggregation and finally
simple metrics gets stored to graphite

What I am thinking is to use Prometheus directly from Kafka and ingest 100 million events in a distributed fashion like from n instance

Spark aggregation are simple so I am thinking of this direct ingestion.

My question is has anyone done such a use case and scale for Prometheus.